# how to add login for tomcat manager default page

Tags: tomcat

I can add login requirement for my webapp using

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user password="mypassword" roles="manager-gui" username="root"/>
```

in tomcat-users.xml in conf folder.
However, anyone can access the default manager page by

```
http:\\myipaddress:8080\
```

How could I block this access or set login requirement for this page?
I have searched around and tried some method but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to have the Tomcat home page

```
TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/ROOT/index.jsp
```

perform a redirect to your start page or the custome page which you want to show.